# Scroll issues with styling

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to re-create navbar which goes away when you scroll down and does opposite when you scroll up. https://codepen.io/retqs/pen/WNNeWeV

I've read about state,like 'your style should be in state in order to change them' but I can't figure out how to make it through the state

```js
  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.scrollNav);
  }

  scrollNav = () => {
    const nav = document.querySelector('.navbar');
    const prevPos = window.pageYOffset;

    const currentPos = window.pageYOffset;
    if (prevPos > currentPos) {
      nav.style.top = '0';
    } else {
      nav.stye.top = '-80px';
    }
  };
```

It throws me an error like that: TypeError: Cannot set property 'top' of undefined

Comment: nav.style is not defined.  Without your html, can't really help

Comment: Not to solve the main issue but you're assigning the same thing to `prevPos` and `currentPos` -- They're always going to be the same value.

Comment: This is react, so only html tag that I have is root

Comment: you have made a typo on your else. nav.stye.top

Comment: ahh ,yeah thanks, that typo was a mistake, now I should solve problem with the same positions